show image from network url in flutter
I have an url that does not contain any image extension instants it contains signature, how can i view image file from that url.
the image url is:
"{baseurl}/media/3775?signature=be8bdb2f88131f506c72fbf6d02127f561a391533854755d8ac7285570a6dd9a"


you show the image using Image widget - in your case Image.network would be the easiest

doc https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/network-image

I have tried it, but does not work because the url does not contain the file extension

it does not have to contain any file extension - if you dont see your Image.network whats the stacktrace you got?

"https://icircles.app/media/4738?signature=ab3959e96ded99d1ba238209816f4d0eb08333491c03551397a4f8d4a7c88d16" this is the real image url. can you try it ?

if you run curl -IL https://icircles.app/media/3775\?signature\=be8bdb2f88131f506c72fbf6d02127f561a391533854755d8ac7285570a6dd9a you will see: cache-control: no-cache, private content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 date: Sun, 05 May 2024 06:18:49 GMT server: LiteSpeed - check the content-type - it is not a image/..., its text/html - thats why Image.network cannot decode it

You Must Have to use Image.network("url"). widget to display your network image into your application
see the example of my coding
Image.network("${baseurl}/media/3775?signature=be8bdb2f88131f506c72fbf6d02127f561a391533854755d8ac7285570a6dd9a")

Thansk for Reading
For more information click this link
